# Цветовая тема для Sublime Text 3

Tags: golang, sublime-text

Здравствуйте. Я в ближайшее время буду писать код на языке golang. В редакторе Sublime Text 3 (не зря приобрел кстати, классная вещь). Так вот столкнулся с проблемами цветовых тем. Раньше, когда кодил в Eclipse, выбора особо не было. Нормальную тёмную тему туда пристроить было проблематично. Но теперь-то выбор есть. И у меня к вам вопрос: стоит ли разделять темы на тему для дня и для ночи, а если стоит — то как? На первый взгляд мне понравилось использовать solarized light днем, и solarized night - ночью. Но мне интересно выслушать ваши мнения.

Comment: неужели никто не пользуется саблаймом?

Comment: Вы это... Начните в ближайшее время, а темы-то на потом оставьте, а то, как говорится, плохому танцору яйца мешают :) Без обид, просто знавал я многих, которые по два года не могли определиться, где лучше начать(!) писать код - в NetBeans или Eclipse, - скакали то туда, то сюда, вместо того чтобы за это время шагнуть дальше понимания разницы между `public` и `private`. 
P.S. Без обид :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос, конечно, вкуса. Не слышал, что-бы кто-то как вы разделяли темы по **освещённости за окном**. Сам использую **Monokai** и доволен.

Искренне не понимаю вашей проблемы. Если нравится использовать разные темы, то почему нет?

Comment: Это и не проблема совсем. Просто было интересно мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Использую одну тему 24/7. Кусок конфига:

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/User/Monokai Soda.tmTheme",
  "theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme",
  "font_face": "Inconsolata LGC",
  "font_size": 14,
}
```